# Cómo puedo establecer en css para mostrar un margin-left en desktop y otro distinto en mobile?

Tags: css

Dejo 2 capturas de pantalla, me gustaría cambiar el margen de desplegable "Elegí una opción" en la versión desktop y que en la versión mobile me quede tal cual se ve en la captura de pantalla.

Este es el código que quiero diferenciar:

```
.woocommerce div.product form.cart .variations select 
{

    border-radius: 100px;
    color: #848484;
    border-color: #848484;
  
}
```

1 Versión desktop
[image: Versión desktop]

2 Versión mobile
[image: Versión mobile]

Comment: Gracias Marce, ahi lo agregue

Answer (score 1):

Esto se hace diferenciando por el tamaño de la pantalla, según que tamaño escojes un estilo o otro. (via Media Query) [Aquí tienes una guía muy completa](https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/news/como-establecer-rango-de-ancho-para-tus-css-media-queries/).

Un resumen seria:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
    // hacer algo, modificar una variable...
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 576px) {
    // volver hacer algo, modificar una variable...
}
```

Un ejemplo quizás mas entendedor sería:

```
.contenedor {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

// modificaremos la clase contenedor si el dispositivo que lo muestra se encuentra en el rango de 320-576 pixeles (el screen)    
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 576px) {
  .contenedor {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 23px;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
  .cajas {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!